# Connect to Azure Redis Cache via HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, azure, redis

I'm using "ServiceStack.Redis" to connect to Redis and it works correctly on my development machine.

Basically, I open the connection via this line:

```
client = new RedisClient(host);
```

Where `host`, on my development machine, is "localhost".

Now, I'd like to upload my application to Azure, so I created a cache in Azure and I'm trying to connect to it by passing the following connection string:

> XXX.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=false,password=YYY

The creation of the "RedisClient" seems to work but when I try to perform an operation (the first one to be executed being `client.RemoveByPattern("...")`), I get the following error:

> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is
>   known

Note that I allowed the cache to be connected to via HTTP, so normally, the port 6379 is unblocked and accessible.

All the example I found over Internet are using "ConnectionMultiplexer" but this class does not seem to be found in the NuGet package "ServiceStack.Redis".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: You’re using the wrong connection string, see [ServiceStack.Redis connection strings](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/README.md#redis-connection-strings) for examples also check out [ServiceStack.Redis and Azure Redis SSL support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/README.md#servicestackredis-ssl-support).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same(similar?) issue connecting to Azure Redis with ServiceStack, in the end it was working out the correct syntax for the connection that worked for me.  XXX.redis.cache.windows.net?ssl=true

Found some help here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis, but to quote the connection strings section had examples;

"Redis Connection strings have been expanded to support the more versatile URI format which is now able to capture most of Redis Client settings in a single connection string (akin to DB Connection strings).

Redis Connection Strings supports multiple URI-like formats, from a simple hostname or IP Address and port pair to a fully-qualified URI with multiple options specified on the QueryString."

Some examples of supported formats:

```
localhost
127.0.0.1:6379
redis://localhost:6379
password@localhost:6379
clientid:password@localhost:6379
redis://clientid:password@localhost:6380?ssl=true&db=1
```

NOTE: I used the final example here but without the redis:// bit as I found this was not needed in Azure.

Comment: Also see [ServiceStack.Redis SSL Support + connecting to Azure Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/README.md#servicestackredis-ssl-support)

Comment: Yeah, you pinpoint the exact cause.  It's because our Azure Redis server only accepts SSL requests.  The problem is that the K6 redis client is hard coded to only use TCP (without SSL).  When I allow non-ssl requests, it works.  But for security, I'm going to have to keep it as SSL only.